# C#: 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow

[image]
Today in the morning I was testing my code suddenly I got this error. I don't know what to do here because it was working file till yesterday night.

I check Stackoverflow website for solution, but the solutions are based on the original code and it's local.

I hope someone can tell me what is the problem here?? Is there any solution for this problem??

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from your data. The XML file appears to contain a circular reference of some kind. I would suggest double-checking its contents.

Comment: I second @FrédéricHamidi. Post your file, maybe, if it isn't too big.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan: The file is too big... What should i do??

Comment: Start breaking it down until you find the culprit.

Comment: Have you tried to read it with an external utility like [XMLNotepad](http://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/releases/view/3791)?. Perhaps this can give you an hint where is the problem.

Comment: It's probably most useful to inspect your XML file, but what are the exception details? Can one see a stack trace (I know it's a `StackOverflowException`) even if you don't have the source code for `mscorlib.dll`?

Comment: Perhaps one of your property setters assigns to the property instead of the underlying field. `int MyProperty{set{MyPropery=value;}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is probably not valid XML anymore possibly due to a circular reference. Either drill down and check if subsets have the problem. Or try a few tools to se if they can more quickly pinpoint the problem. With tools I mean apps like xmlspy (or even an online check like http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp)

Comment: How would a circular reference in an XML file look like?

Comment: Thx god finally :) you save my life : My circular reference was SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Answer (score 0):

in my C# Windows form application code the circular reference (not in XML file) which thrown the "System.StackOverFlowException" looked like this, The approach I took was breaking step by step as per @zmbq's comment:

```
class A
{
//Class A code

class B
{
    //Class B code
}
}

class C
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C(); /*CALLING THE SAME CONSTRUCTOR IN CIRCULAR FASHION*/
}
```

I removed the constructor call to class C (which was actually necessary), now it works fine!!